# PostgreSQL check value from sum in where

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm triyng to add a the *done* value to where clause, so I can show only results from todo, that are already done, but keep getting an error:

```
select "todo", SUM( "test"."count" ) as "done"
from B 
Where "done" =  "todo"
```

this is the error:

> q_driver: [PGRES_FATAL_ERROR]ERRORE:  the column "done" don't exist

but the column is displayed if I remove the where clause

Comment: where is `test` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `alias` name in same `select` query `where` clause

```
select * from
(
select "todo", SUM( "test"."count" ) as "done"
from B 
GROUP BY "todo"
)
Where "done" =  "todo"
```